# apt error after upgrading ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04

after i upgraded ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 i get this error when i tried `sudo apt update`

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Stats '[ ! -f /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook ] || /usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

please any fix?
even some packages stopped working like nautilus

Comment: You tagged your release as Ubuntu 14.04? but question text mentions much later releases... are we missing something?  (the ESM hook in the message does make readers think you are using 14.04 ESM thus you tag is correct, question text wrong maybe)

Comment: Sorry about that I has been corrected.